# Is it possible to use action="someFunction()" when a form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

From looking around on the web, I have not seen many examples of setting a function equal to a function. However, in the few forums I found, it appears that many say that this method is not widely supported.

To explain my question, I have a form I would like to implement this on:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
                <th colspan="2" align="center">Check Out</th>
                <form name="checkOut" method="post" onSubmit="return(validate(this))" action="checkOut()"> 
                    <tr><td>Territory Number</td><td><input type="text" name="numberOut" tabindex="1" maxlength="3" size="3" /></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>First Name of Publisher</td><td><input type="text" onKeyUp="showHint(this.value)" name="fName" tabindex="2" maxlength="15"/></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>Last Name of Publisher</td><td><input type="text" onKeyUp="showHint_l(this.value)" name="lName" tabindex="3" maxlength="15" /></td>
                    </tr><tr><td><input type ="checkbox" name="specialC" tabindex="4" value="Yes"/> Special Campaign</td>
                    </tr><tr><td><input type="button" onClick="clearForm()" value="Reset" /></td><td><input type="submit" value="Check Out" /></td>
                </form>
                <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
            </table>
```

More specifically, the checkOut() function will be using ajax to submit the form values to a php script that runs a few insert commands against a database (I want to use ajax to learn the technique as I'm fairly new to web-based languages. Therefore, I want to put off the use of jQuery for awhile). As of right now, I don't have an example of the function.

Naturally, that begs the question, could I simply put that function into the event handler: onSubmit = "checkOut()"? At the same time, I would leave action=""? I would assume that the entire function would execute the php script and do exactly what I want without having a separate action script.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<input type="button" />` (or an anchor, or a `button`, or whatever) instead of `<input type="submit" />`. On the click event of the button, execute:

```
if(validate(document.getElementById("formId"))){
    // post the form w/ AJAX
    checkOut();
}
```

Keep in mind that any script-based solution should probably have a non-script option. In this case, it could be as easy as putting an `<input type="submit" />` inside `noscript` tags.

Incidentally, your markup is invalid. A `form` can't appear as a direct child of a `table`.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it the `action="javascript:checkOut();"` but it would almost certainly be better to put it in the `onSubmit` handler.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was figuring that would be the case, but  from looking at many forums it appears that there are many ambiguous answers.

Answer (score 0):

use this code is the best way to do that

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_button">
```

and javascript code like this

```
var submit = getElementById('submit_button');
submit.preventDefault();
submit.addEventListener('click', checkOut);
```

in first line we specific the button and next we prevent to do the default action and next we add a listener for when button clicked

Answer (score 0):

I typically use:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction();">
```

And then my function would use the native submit function at the bottom if everything checks out.:

```
if (isSuccess)
    theForm.submit();
else
    return false;
```